# How to write test case using jQuery in ember framework

Tags: ember.js

This is JavaScript/jQuery to test drag n drop in ember:
I am not sure why it is not running:

```
test('dragdrop', function(assert){
   this.render(hbs`{{dragdrop}}`);
(function(export){
   var datatransfermock = function (){};
   datatransfermock.prototype.setdata = function(format,data){
   this[format]= data;
   };
   datatransfermock.prototype.getdata = function(format){
   if(this.hasownproperty(format)){
   return this[format];
   }else{
      return null;
   }
 };
exports.datatransferMock=Datatransfermock;
})(window);
ember.run(function(){
   var sourcedata = this.$('.draggable:eq(0)'),
   targetdata = this.$('.draggable:eq(1)'),
   datastartevent = $.event('dragstart'),
   dropevent - $.event('drop');
   dragstartevent.datatransfer = new datatransfermock();
   sourcedata.trigger(dragstartevent);
   dropevent.datatransfer = dragstartevent.datatransfer;
   targetdata.trigger(dropevent);
   sourcedata.trigger('dragend');
 });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I had tried using ember.run(function()){trigger event(classname, 'drag') and triggerevent(classname1, 'drop')}; in my unit test

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that contained some testing strategies for integration tests.  Might work for unit testing as well: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/drag-and-drop-divs/4031/5

Thanks for the question.  I have been wondering about that myself.

Update:  I notice that where you render the component, you don't have backticks surrounding it.  I will update the answer to include an example once I get to a computer, as I can't type backticka on my phone.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case it is not triggering the events

Comment: Do you have an Ember twiddle or some code to show us?

Comment: sorry for late reply, i have added my test cases by editing the question

Comment: Added my query in ember discuss also. Just want to know in my trigger code why the event didn't got fired